# Tomcat webapp not found 404 error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, server, http-status-code-404

I have web-apps deployed on my server, lets call them ABC and XYZ. **I want to show a custom error page page when I try to access an unknown web-app**. For example if I try to access localhost/asdfasd it should display my custome error page.

I have tried adding something like below in conf/web.xml, but it doesn't work I still see the default Tomcat 404 error page.

```
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/error/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

But the error-page works when I use it in web.xml of each web-app. So when I try access localhost/ABC/non_existing_page I see my custom error page.

Comment: Did you try these suggestions? https://serverfault.com/a/254112

Comment: @clinomaniac Thanks for the reply, Yes I did try that, it doesn't seem to work.